# Cast table name to OID using jooq

Tags: sql, postgresql, jooq

I need to cast a table name to object identifier using JOOQ. In plain SQL I would do:

```
'my_table'::regclass::oid
```

I couldn't find a DataType for casting the value (It exists a `PostgresDataType.OID`, but not a `PostgresDataType.REGCLASS` or something similar, also using `PostgresDataType` directly is deprecated).

I also played with `DSL.inline`, `DSL.val`, but can't obtain the desired output.

**UPDATE**

I realized there's a `PostgresDSL.oid` that returns `Field<Long>` and produces following output `"my_table".oid`, but I don't have a reference for the table (I have the table name as text), so it's not valid for my use case.

---

Is there a way to cast a table name to Postgres Object Identifier (OID) throught JOOQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time testing I found a working solution (Not sure the best).

```
DSL.field("{0}::regclass::oid", DSL.inline(name))
```

This way we create a "field" with all the castings needed hardcoded and set the value as a binding.

Comment: *"Not sure the best"* - Yes, that's the way to go here

Comment: Thank you for reviewing and for te good work @Lukas. jooq helped me a lot!